# Python Dataframe Masking

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi Please help with dataframe question.

I am trying to select dated rows from a dataframe and for the with statement as below.

What am I doing wrong?

```
startDate = '2019-01-01 00:00:00'
endDate = '2019-01-31 00:00:00'

mask = (df['date'] <= endDate) & (df['date'] >= starDate)
```

when I print df.loc[mask] It doesn't include the endDate, even tough I am saying <=. And Yes.. its is in the data set.

Comment: please include a sample of the data you're working with

Comment: what dtype is your ```'date'``` column?

Comment: which time-part?

Comment: Please include a sample of the data you are operating on! Have you checked if the data types if each individual condition that you have specified works?

Comment: yes.  I get the full month, except for 1/31

Comment: you probably want to make your `endDate = '2019-01-31 23:59:59'`

Comment: Or perhaps less than Feb 1 :D

Comment: In general convert datetimes to date in order to avoid such problems when you are refering to dates and not timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include the data from 1/31, you should set the mask to the last second of that day. Something like

```
endDate = '2019-01-31 23:59:59'
```

---

OR set it equal to the start of the next day

```
endDate = '2019-02-01 00:00:00'
```

and change your mask to

```
mask = (df['date'] < endDate) & (df['date'] >= startDate)
```

Comment: [@wpercy] that is probably the issue.. thanks so much.

Comment: would you know why this is like almost 25% slower?            
  mask = (df['date'].dt.year == year) & (df['date'].dt.month == month)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 mask = df.date.isin(pd.date_range(start='2019-01-01 00:00:00', end='2019-01-31 00:00:00'))
```

or

```
mask = df.date.isin(pd.date_range(start=startDate, end=endDate))
```

which outupts:

```
Out[73]:
2018-03-31    False
2018-04-30    False
2018-05-31    False
2018-06-30    False
2018-07-31    False
2018-08-31    False
2018-09-30    False
2018-10-31    False
2018-11-30    False
2018-12-31    False
2019-01-31     True
2019-02-28    False
2019-03-31    False
2019-04-30    False
Freq: M, Name: date, dtype: bool
```

Comment: I original problem. but tried above to see if its faster, but it doesn't actually return any results at all.  Can start and end be dttype?

Comment: you can use a string like date or a datetime type.